# Broadcast not triggered when process is created

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast which monitors for unlock event for the phone. But when the app's process is killed and no longer in memory, Unlocking the phone does not trigger the Receiver, instead I can see in the Android studio, that new process is created for that app.

If lock and unlock it again, then as the process is already running, I can see the `BroadcastReceiver` is triggered.

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".UserPresentBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class UserPresentBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = UserPresentBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: Unlock Boradcast received");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "You just unlocked the device",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to understand this behavior. Is this the default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You have to register and unregister this broadcast receiver in Activity(or Service for listening in background all the time).
Manifest entry won't work.

Comment: It works. Actually when I first time unlock the device, it creates the process. The second time I unlock the device, It shown me the toast message.  And from the second time, all the time it works just fine. Again after it is removed from the memory, the first time unlock doesn't trigger the broadcast receiver.